# Watchguard dimension backups

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, watchguard, logserver

I've got a virtual machine with Watchguard dimension OS which writes a database backup every 7 days: I haven't checked for a couple of months but when I've logged on I've seen that the /var mountpoint is full and then is over a month that the vm isn't writing a single backup (without a warning).

I've tried to enter in console (with user wgsupport) and delete the various zip under /var/opt/watchguard/dimension/wlogserver/backup but I cannot because those files are belonging to wgadmin and I don't have the password neither to delete, neither to su/sudo and then do the operations needed.

I also cannot extend the /var partition because the lvextend utils aren't installed and without being su I cannot even install it.

Anyone has faced this kind of problem and has resolved it? I've tried to search some informations but I haven't found anything useful.

Thanks

Comment: What does Watchguard support have to say about this?

Comment: Nothing on their site, I think I will need to contact them by email in as soon as possible if I won't be able to resolve fast